# Ball game - changing ball position

Tags: android, position, coordinates

I am making simple ball game and l have problem.I can't change position of Ball.
I tried:

1. SetX() and setY() but lower APIs aren't supported.
2. Params and margins but when I move it left or right, the whole activity content is moving with it. Up and down moving is working fine. (Activity will have 10 ImageViews)
3. Android animations - Problem is that I can't get coorinates (getLeft(), getTop()) during the animation.
4. Canvas and draw elements - I change position of image with onDraw() and invalidate() functions but when I but backgorund and all other images (as bitmaps) it is very slow.

Can you give to me any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *VerticalLayout* and then change position with params